# How to find information about all the AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I use this to display information about the particular AMI:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids "ami-xxxxxxxx"
```

And it gives me information about the image.

What if there are multiple AMI, is there a way I can get information about all the AMI and store them in a file?
Is this possible, or is there another better way?

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:
aws ec2 describe-images --filters file://images.json

Where images.json contains:

[
{
    "Name":"image-id",
    "Values": ["aki-xxx","aki-xxx"]
}
]

Answer (score 0):

You can list all your AMI's using filters along with your code you mentioned.
Try this:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --region <Your-specific-region>
--filter "Name=is-public,Values=false" --filter 
"Name=architecture, Values=x86_64" --filter 
"Name=owner,Values=xxxx"
```

Use owner as the owner of AMI's to filter out. 
And then you can save the output in a file.

Hope it will help !

Comment: Yes, it did help. I was able to pull up information of all the AMI in a particular region.

Comment: Sure, I would do it. 
I have a sub-question;
How would I pull up information using parameters.
ex: I need AMI and need specific information about that ami. Like, name, description, snapshotID, etc?

Comment: Use filters buddy .. every time you call this api describe-images u get all the meta data .. just you need to format your output using filters for whatever u need be it name ..snapshotid from which it was created etc.

Comment: For example: if u need a ami with its snapshot id you can run this :.      $ aws ec2 describe-images --filter Name=tag:source,Values=xyz | jq ".Images[0].ImageId,.Images[0].BlockDeviceMappings[0].Ebs.SnapshotId"

Comment: Source= xyz as tag

Comment: I am not sure, I understand that very well.

Lets say: aws ec2 describe-images --region us-east-1

This will give me AMI in the entire region.

What parameters should I add in this statement: aws ec2 describe-images --region us-east-1

That will only provide me information limited to snapshotID, Name, etc.

Comment: I would recommend you to follow this link : [LINK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-images.html#examples)

Comment: There just focus on the output : 
you will get the snapshot id inside blockdevicemapping 
so the code i gave you earlier will select the image id ..then to the blockdevice mapping inside that ebs and then fetches the snapshot id 



"BlockDeviceMappings": [
                {
                    "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
                    "Ebs": {
                        "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                        "SnapshotId": "snap-1234567890abcdef0",
                        "VolumeSize": 8

Comment: @JohnRotenstein you have tagged the wrong person sir , I am the one who is answering.